# g++ rejects my simple functor with "expected a type, got 'xyz'"

Tags: c++, templates, g++, functor

I've been playing about with functors in C++. In particular, I've got a vector of pairs I'd like to sort by the first element of the pair. I started off writing a completely specialised functor (i.e. something like "bool MyLessThan(MyPair &lhs, MyPair &rhs)"). Then, just because this sort of stuff is interesting, I wanted to try writing a generic "Apply F to the first elements of this pair" functor. I wrote the below, but g++ doesn't like it. I get:

error: type/value mismatch at argument 2 in template parameter list for 'template struct Pair1stFunc2'
error:   expected a type, got 'less'

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

template <class P, class F>
struct Pair1stFunc2
{
    typename F::result_type operator()(P &lhs, P &rhs) const
    { return F(lhs.first, rhs.first); }

    typename F::result_type operator()(const P &lhs, const P &rhs) const
    { return F(lhs.first, rhs.first); }
};

typedef std::pair<int,int> MyPair;
typedef std::vector<MyPair> MyPairList;

MyPairList pairs;

void foo(void)
{
    std::sort(pairs.begin(),
              pairs.end(),
              Pair1stFunc2<MyPair, std::less>());
}
```

Can anyone shed any light on what I'm doing wrong here? I know this is as slightly artificial example, but I'd like to know what's going on, if only to improve my STL-fu.

Comment: Once you resolve this problem, you'll have another because F is a type. You're constructing a new F using lhs.first and rhs.first. You'll find that std::less doesn't have a two-argument constructor. You need to have a *value* of type F.

Comment: Here's something to improve your boost::bind-fu: sort(p.begin(), p.end(), bind(less<int>(), bind(&MyPair::first, _1), bind(&MyPair::first, _2))); ;) http://codepad.org/NouR5fko

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specialize std::less with the comparison type you're using.

```
Pair1stFunc2<MyPair, std::less<int> >()
```

will do the trick.  Within your own operator() you'll also need to instantiate an object of the comparison type, since you can't just call the class directly.  E.g. change

```
return F(lhs.first, rhs.first);
```

to

```
F func;
return func(lhs.first, rhs.first);
```

You could also move the specialization into the functor, as another answer suggests.

Comment: He's not actually using std::less with MyPair, though, but std::less<int> instead.

Answer (score 6):

To expand on dirkgently's answer, here's an example of what might work as you intend:

```
template <typename T, template <typename> class F>
struct Pair1stFunc2
{
    template <typename P>
    typename F<T>::result_type operator()(P &lhs, P &rhs) const
    { F<T> f; return f(lhs.first, rhs.first); }

    template <typename P>
    typename F<T>::result_type operator()(const P &lhs, const P &rhs) const
    { F<T> f; return f(lhs.first, rhs.first); }
};

void foo(void)
{
    std::sort(pairs.begin(),
              pairs.end(),
              Pair1stFunc2<int, std::less>());
}
```

Note that it works, but it might not be exactly what you had in mind.

Comment: This works, but template template parameters are actually unnecessary here because you only ever refer to F as "F<T>" -- see Martin York's answer, which will also work for non-templated comparators.

Comment: boost mpl lambda expression comes handy here. just pass std::less<_> you could write  "typename F" then and do typename mpl::apply<F, int>::type f; instead to get a std::less<int> which i find very nice, especially when you have some template that could take additionally optional arguments (like std::vector template), you just could pass std::vector<_>

Answer (score 3):

Note that `std::less` is itself a template and you do not specify the template template parameter when you call it from with `foo()` function's `sort`! Here `less` is an incomplete type and hence the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to unwesen. But you don't need to use template templates.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

typedef std::pair<int,int> MyPair;
typedef std::vector<MyPair> MyPairList;
MyPairList pairs;


// Same as original.
template <typename T,typename F>
struct Pair1stFunc2
{
    template <typename P>
    typename F::result_type operator()(P &lhs, P &rhs) const
    { F f;  // Just need to create an anstance of the functor to use.
      return f(lhs.first, rhs.first); }

    template <typename P>
    typename F::result_type operator()(const P &lhs, const P &rhs) const
    { F f;  // Just need to create an anstance of the functor to use.
      return f(lhs.first, rhs.first); }
};


void foo(void)
{
    std::sort(pairs.begin(),
              pairs.end(),
              Pair1stFunc2<int, std::less<int> >()); // initialize the version of less
}
```

Comment: +1. This is more general than unwesel's solution because it will also work for non-templated comparators.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to state what you want as an argument, a function with a suitable signature:

```
template<typename P, bool (*F)(P,P)> struct Pair1stFunc2 { ... }
```

In this case, passing a function template as the second argument will cause overload resolution to be done on it with P,P as argument types. This works because you move the overload resolution out of `struct Pair1stFunc2::operator()`

You also want the possibility of passing in a *functor*, but those do need to be passed as a template type argument and then created inside operator() :

```
typename F::result_type operator()(const P &lhs, const P &rhs) const
{ return F()(lhs.first, rhs.first); }
```

Here, F is the functor type and F() an instance of that functor.

The third case is already covered earlier, the functor template. std::less is such a template. In that case, you need a template template argument.

Comment: Basically correct, but I'd say that instances of std::less<T> are functors. A functor can be called using the syntax F(argument-list). You can't call std::less like that.

Comment: (deleted my comment because it referred to the answer before it was edited)

Comment: Are you proposing two separate syntaxes for Pair1stFunc2::operator()(lhs, rhs), one for function pointers, another for functors? Granted, your solution using a function pointer template parameter should be smaller and faster for that case, but you can use a single syntax by having Pair1stFunc2 take two template *type* parameters (P and F) and store a member f of type F (this can be populated in a 1-arg ctor for the function pointer case). Then operator()(lhs, rhs) can say "return f(lhs.first, rhs.first);".

Comment: Actually proposing three templates, but they would have similar syntaxes.  Pair1stFunc2<P, function>, Pair1stFunc2<P, functor_type> and Pair1stFunc2<P, functor_template>. Their operator()s are quite similar.

Comment: @MSalters: Ah thanks. +1 for the first of the three which should definitely give a speed-up for the function pointer case (a direct, possibly even inlined call instead of an indirect call).